# Insert a UNIQUE DUMMY COLUMN when creating VIEW with UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with this structure:

[image]

I use this script to query the requests:

```
SELECT   D.DELIVERY_REQUEST_ID AS "REQUEST_ID",
         'Delivery' AS "REQUEST_TYPE"
   FROM  DELIVERY_REQUEST D
UNION
SELECT   I.INVOICE_REQUEST_ID AS "REQUEST_ID",
         'Invoice' AS "REQUEST_TYPE"
   FROM  INVOICE_TRX I
```

The result would be like this:

```
    REQUEST_ID    |    REQUEST_TYPE
__________________|____________________
                  |
    1             |    Delivery
    1             |    Invoice
    2             |    Delivery
    2             |    Invoice
```

What I want to do is to query (or create a view) this with a unique key (should be an INT and like an auto number) at the beginning like this:

```
ID  |  REQUEST_ID    |    REQUEST_TYPE
____|________________|____________________
    |                |
1   |  1             |    Delivery
2   |  1             |    Invoice
3   |  2             |    Delivery
4   |  2             |    Invoice
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, as you're adding a string use UNION ALL so Oracle doesn't try to do a distinct sort.

To actually answer the question you can use the analytic function [ROW_NUMBER()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100)

```
select row_number() over ( order by request_id, request_type ) as id
     , a.*
  from ( select d.delivery_request_id as request_id
              , 'delivery' as request_type
           from delivery_request d
          union all
         select i.invoice_request_id as request_id
              , 'invoice' as request_type
           from invoice_trx i
                ) a
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I never thought of that. I'm so noob. Thanks @Ben.

Answer (score 1):

why you dont try to concat `REQUEST_TYPE + REQUEST_ID` and then put it in column `ID` instead of generate ids?

```
ID  |  REQUEST_ID    |    REQUEST_TYPE
____|________________|____________________
    |                |
D1  |  1             |    Delivery
I1  |  1             |    Invoice
D2  |  2             |    Delivery
I2  |  2             |    Invoice
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use rownum :

```
select rownum, REQUEST_ID, REQUEST_TYPE
from
(
SELECT   D.DELIVERY_REQUEST_ID AS "REQUEST_ID",
         'Delivery' AS "REQUEST_TYPE"
   FROM  DELIVERY_REQUEST D
UNION
SELECT   I.INVOICE_REQUEST_ID AS "REQUEST_ID",
         'Invoice' AS "REQUEST_TYPE"
   FROM  INVOICE_TRX I
)
```

Comment: Without an explicit ORDER BY, and thus another sub-select you cannot guarantee order via this method.

Comment: I don't quite understand the "you cannot guarantee order" comment, did I miss something where the order of the records needs to be guaranteed?  I'm currently using ROWNUM instead of ROW_NUMBER(); if I don't care about the order of the records will that work just as well or should I be rewriting it?

Answer (score -1):

I'd say a sequence would be the easiest way.
If you want the ID to always start at 1, restart the sequence before the query:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE temp_id RESTART 1;
```

Don't know how fast this is, slash whether there are faster methods. Certain SQL systems might also have special features for this, in extension of the standard SQL.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support this syntax.  Also it would be a very bad idea to issue DDL before every SELECT, because DDL (again, in Oracle) issues COMMITs and that would play havoc with any transactions.  Finally it simply would work in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Well you could issue the DDL before opening the transaction. Not familiar with Oracle though, sorry.